# How can I get this flexbox to expand with it's flex items?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

**In my example code, please click on the Generate Content button in order to understand the issue.**

Once you click on the button, you can see all of the flex items(`.each-result`) generate. They are *almost* completely wrapped by the div/flexbox (`.result-container`), indicated by the blue dotted border. If I remove the margins from flex-items, it fits perfectly into the div. However, when I add the margins, the parent div (ie. the flexbox) doesn't expand to it's full width; it remains the same width as when there was no margin.

Is there anyway to change this so that the div expands when adding margin?

```js
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('#left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('#right-arrow');
const rootDiv = document.querySelector('#root');
const generateButton = document.querySelector("#button-generate");
var navMargin = '';
let rootContainerWidth = window.getComputedStyle(rootDiv, null).getPropertyValue("width");
console.log(`Window size onload: ${rootContainerWidth}`);
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  rootContainerWidth = window.getComputedStyle(rootDiv, null).getPropertyValue("width");
  console.log(`The new window size is ${rootContainerWidth}`);
})
//This code basically generates the content within the div
generateButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add("each-result");
    newDiv.appendChild(addImg("https://uk.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/please_read_icon_150x150.jpg"));
    rootDiv.appendChild(newDiv);  
  }
  rootDiv.firstElementChild.classList.add('nav-margin');
  navMargin = document.querySelector('.nav-margin');
});

//These enable the arrow to scroll through the dynamically generated content
// function navArrow () {
//   leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
 
//   });
// rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   if ()
//   });
// }




//Simple function to create and image element with the src attribute set in one line
function addImg(url) {
  const newImg = document.createElement("img");
  newImg.setAttribute("src", url);
  return newImg;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  z-index: 0
}

.each-result {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 3px dotted red;
  margin: 0 1%;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.nav-arrows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background: clear;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#left-arrow, #right-arrow {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#root-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
  width: 100%;
}

.result-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px blue dotted;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-arrows">
      <button id="left-arrow"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i>
      </button>
        <button id="right-arrow"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  <div id="root-container">
  <div id="root" class="result-container">
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
<button id="button-generate">Generate Content</button>
```

Comment: As the dupe suggests, all you need is to e.g. use viewport units instead of percent for the margin, `margin: 0 1vw`.

Comment: Adding `margin: 0 1vw;` does not produce the desired result.

Comment: Using Viewport units definitely did the trick. I did appreciated your other answer as well though.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Of course it does (and so says the OP). In this case 1% is picked up from the parent, which has full viewport width, and with that 1% = 1 vw.

Comment: Agree to disagree @LGSon. With the `1vw` the spacing is not the same.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody You mean in above case, where 1% does not generate the same spacing as 1vw does?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Or you mean that 1% of an element that takes 100% of the viewport is not the same as 1vw?

Comment: The former - `1vw` does not produce the same result as `1%`.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Exactly...and the duplicate explains why, and in this case, where the parent take full viewport width, 1% would in a non-flex setup be the same as 1vw, hence 1vw can be used to achieve the _wanted_ output.

Answer (score 0):

If the `margin` can be a fixed value (instead of a percent), we can `calc()` the width of the element to account for the margin. For example, if we wanted a margin of `20px` we'd do the following on the `.each-result` elements:

```
.each-result {
  width: calc(10% + 20px);
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

Here's the working demo:

```js
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('#left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('#right-arrow');
const rootDiv = document.querySelector('#root');
const generateButton = document.querySelector("#button-generate");
var navMargin = '';
let rootContainerWidth = window.getComputedStyle(rootDiv, null).getPropertyValue("width");
console.log(`Window size onload: ${rootContainerWidth}`);
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  rootContainerWidth = window.getComputedStyle(rootDiv, null).getPropertyValue("width");
  console.log(`The new window size is ${rootContainerWidth}`);
})
//This code basically generates the content within the div
generateButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add("each-result");
    newDiv.appendChild(addImg("https://uk.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/please_read_icon_150x150.jpg"));
    rootDiv.appendChild(newDiv);  
  }
  rootDiv.firstElementChild.classList.add('nav-margin');
  navMargin = document.querySelector('.nav-margin');
});

//These enable the arrow to scroll through the dynamically generated content
// function navArrow () {
//   leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
 
//   });
// rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   if ()
//   });
// }




//Simple function to create and image element with the src attribute set in one line
function addImg(url) {
  const newImg = document.createElement("img");
  newImg.setAttribute("src", url);
  return newImg;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  z-index: 0
}

.each-result {
  height: 150px;
  width: calc(10% + 20px);
  margin: 0 20px;
  border: 3px dotted red;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.nav-arrows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background: clear;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#left-arrow, #right-arrow {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#root-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
  width: 100%;
}

.result-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px blue dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-arrows">
      <button id="left-arrow"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i>
      </button>
        <button id="right-arrow"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  <div id="root-container">
  <div id="root" class="result-container">
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
<button id="button-generate">Generate Content</button>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason start messing with `calc();`, this is completely related to the issue when using percent on flex children, so I closed this as a duplicate.